# There are 100 people, two from each of the 50 houses

Tags: probability

In a big neighborhood, there are 100 people, two from each of the 50 different houses.

If 12 people are chosen to be evacuated for a zombie apocalypse, what is the probability that they are all from different houses?  What is the probability that neither of the two picked people are from the same house?

Can someone look over my work

Answer (score 2):

There are $100\choose 12$ ways in total to choose a dozen evacuuees. Among these are ${50\choose 12}\cdot 2^{12}$ ways that avoid picking two people from the same house. The quotient of these two numbers gives the desired probability that all twelve are from different houses.

Answer (score 0):

For the probability of being in different houses, would it be (50 nCr 12)/(100 nCr 12)
and for the probability of being not from the same house, 1-(50 nCr 2 / 100 nCr 2)?